# Fiware iotagent: How to send measure from a device?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I'm developing a `Fiware` system and I don't know how to send measures from a device through `IDAS` `iot-agent`.

I have Orion and Cygnus running, but I'm sending the measures with a servlet directly to Orion and I want to switch the proccess to `IDAS iot-agent`.

I've created the service and the device properly but I'm stucked with the POST from the device to the iot-agent.

My device is created as follows:

> { "device_id" : "0010", "entity_name" : "0010", "entity_type" :
>   "xxxxx", "timezone" : "Europe/Madrid", "attributes" : [ { "object_id"
>   : "0010", "name" : "fecha", "type" : "timestamp", "name" : "coord_x",
>   "type" : "double", "name" : "coord_y", "type" : "double", "name" :
>   "coderr", "type" : "string", "name" : "s_temp", "type" : "double",
>   "name" : "s_hum", "type" : "double", "name" : "num_sat", "type" :
>   "int", "name" : "voltaje", "type" : "double", "name" : "inicio",
>   "type" : "int" } ], "service" : "xxxxx", "service_path" : "/xxxxx" }

How it would be the POST from the device to send the measures?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried to POST from a command line to test like this:

> curl -X POST xxxxxxxxxxxx:8080/iot/d?i=0010 \
>    -i \
>    -H "Content-Type: application/text" \
>    -H "Fiware-Service: xxxxxx" \
>    -H "Fiware-ServicePath: /xxxxxx" \
>    -d "s_temp|25"

And here is the response:

> HTTP/1.1 415 Connection: close 
>   Content-Length: 88 {"reason": "Unsupported Media Type (only support application/xml and application/json)"}

Now the question is... if I had installed iot-agent-base and iot-agent-ul, Why I'm not able to POST text? Did I miss some configuration?

**EDIT**:

I'm able to send values to this url:

```
http://xxxxxxxx:8080/iot/xx?k=xxxxxxx&i=xxxxxxxx#fecha|1#coord_x|1#coord_y|1#coderr|1#s_temp|1#s_hum|1#s_temp|1#num_sat|1#voltaje|1#inicio|1
```

And this is the respone

```
DEBUG - Accept: */*
DEBUG - End filters status 200
DEBUG - Proccessing in handle /iot
DEBUG - iota::AdminService::error_response 0
DEBUG - finish connection 2
DEBUG - Get statistics /iot/ngsi Counters 0
INFO - Agent Activity {"statistics":[{"resource":"/iot/ngsi","data":[]}]}
```

But Orion doesn't get anything

**EDIT:**

It was a version issue, now I have the latest version of iot-agent installed with UltraLight module and device with "protocol":"PDI-IoTA-UltraLight" and the protocol itself is working.

But I don't know what is the correct url to post measures from the device. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the same URL you were trying before but with -H "Content-Type: application/json" ?

Even when the body is UL2.0 the content-type should be set to JSON.

Let me know if this fix your problem.
Thanks for using IDAS!

Comment: It seems to be working. Now I have to check if Cygnus is saving data like before.

At least Orion is getting something from the IoTAgent and sending to localhost:5050/notify

Thanks

Comment: Cygnus is also getting data. I just had to create a new database and table called as Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath. I will migrate the database or change the IoTAgent service and ServicePath to fit the previous database.

Comment: I am new to Fiware and using latest Orion Context Broker and IDAS (Version 5). I have used Docker Containers for the same.

From https://www.slideshare.net/FI-WARE/fiware-iotidasintroul20v2 when i am trying to send measurement ({{BaseURL}}/d?k=31Jan2018fiwareiot&i=DevID1), i am getting following error. "Cannot POST /iot/d"

Please guide what am i doing wrong?

I have posted a separate question also at Fiware Ultralight 2.0 IoTAgent: How to send measure from a device?

Regards,

Krishan